# Is there any possible way to read message in ms teams before clicking the send button

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create a teams app that will detect the message that user has typed in before the message is sent on clicking the send button or on the send button click event or before the recipient receives the message. The idea is to read the message and using AI grammatically correct the text or detect if any inappropriate message is being sent that violets office rules, kind of like Grammarly. My question is it possible to detect this text through any possible means like graph api. i am open to any suggestion, not just teams app it can be some kind of windows application that can interact with teams app . Will be taking care of AI part myself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported, there is no No event when user is typing message. You can get an event when user sends the message. For more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta)